# Bank account got shut down for fraud from my sugar daddy?

Tags: bank-account, check, fraud, sugar-daddy

I recently met some sugar daddy and gave him my bank username and password for him to deposit money into my account. I had about 9.00$ in my account and he tried depositing 800$, then next day I tried logging into my account and it got shut down.

I called my bank and they told me it’s closed for fraud. Am I going to get in trouble for this or is there any way I can prove that that transaction was not from me?

They shut it down immediately so I doubt the scammer had tried spending the money. But is there any way they can prove that that wasn’t me (like my signature?) or see the location of where the transaction was taken place?

Comment: Does "give him my bank information" mean that you gave him the ABA routing number and account number from a check so that he could transfer money?  Or that you gave him your username & password so he had full access to your account?

Comment: Account information to log onto my account.

Comment: "or see the location of where the transaction was taken place?"  How far away?  Anyway, I hope you learned a lesson about strangers and sugar daddies.

Comment: @RonJohn he told me he lived in L.A. I have never met this guy and he for sure lives in a different state than I do. And yes, I feel like an idiot for giving my account information to someone. Will I be getting in trouble for this? I am supposed to call the bank back on Monday to talk to the person who deals with fraud. Should I mention that my account was hacked and that I wasn’t the one who tried depositing the check? Will I be okay? How can they even accept a check if I didn’t even write my own signature on the back of it ?

Comment: The bank shutting down your account was likely as a **safety** measure, because they detected potentially unauthorized activity. In other words, they probably acted in your favor.

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question asks if it is a scam, this one is "Will I get into trouble and what should I do?" That is not in the answers to that question.

Comment: "gave him my bank username and password" Well, I suppose you knew that you weren't supposed to do that (you read the banks' T&C, didn't you?). So... why?

Comment: @EliseJacobs Who says it was a check?

Answer (score 17):

> Should I mention that my account was hacked?

Your account was **NOT** hacked: you freely gave your credential away.

> and that I wasn’t the one who tried depositing the check?

Yes.  And **tell the truth**, no matter how embarrassing.

> Will I be okay?

Probably.  Tell not just the bank, but go to the police and **tell them everything** you know about him and what you did.

Plead youthful naivete and foolishness, and it's highly unlikely that you'll be charged.

> How can they even accept a check if I didn’t even write my own signature on the back of it ?

The banks want to simplify their lives and make it easier for customers.

Answer (score 11):

Please don't take this first part as a guilt-trip in any way - you're hardly the first person to be scammed in ways similar to this, nor will you be the last. For future reference, though, the fact that he asked for your username and password in order to deposit money into your account should've been a red flag. Why would he need that information? Any particular reason he couldn't have just written you a check? I would definitely recommend familiarizing yourself with common types of financial scams and how to recognize their warning signs. (There are web sites, like [this one](https://www.fraudguides.com/), that provide good guidance on this).

The answer to your specific question will depend in part on exactly what he was involved in. You don't tag which country you're in, but it may be a good idea to consult with an attorney on the laws of your particular jurisdiction. As @RonJohn's answer indicated, you're also definitely going to want to tell both the bank and local law enforcement exactly what happened. In addition to helping you avoiding any further financial or legal fallout from this incident, scammers tend to rely on you being too afraid or embarrassed to come forward in order to keep operating (so you coming forward could help to prevent him from scamming other people in the future).